# Getting arraylist of variable from arraylist of class

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist of class Person

```
ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

Inside that Person class i have some variables associated with that person.

```
public class Person {
    String Name;
    String Address;
    String Phonenumber;
}
```

Now is there a way using the people arraylist to get an arraylist of Name?

Comment: Why do you need a separate array list?  What's wrong with `(people.get(index)).getName()`?

Comment: Epickel, my answer may provide a convenient way of keeping the two arrays in sync if you must have both arrays.

Answer (score 3):

You have to iterate over it.

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

for(Person person : people) {
   names.add(person.getName()); // Assuming you have a getter
}
```

Comment: but will the names arraylist update if I add a new person to the people arraylist?

Comment: No, definitely not. You will have to extend `ArrayList` and provide events or just call it manually when changing the `people` list.

Comment: @Epickel: that's incorrect, `Name` isn't public. It has no modifier. Just to be safe I have commented that I assume a getter, as you can see.

Comment: I'm just wondering if this is even the correct approach as a way to store people for creating a contact application because it seems like such a hassle.

Comment: Why do you need a separate array?  Just access the getName() method on each index of the array of people.

Comment: @nhgrif: he explicitly states "is there a way using the people arraylist to get an arraylist of Name?".

Comment: The question is directed at Epickel's comment, not your answer.  Sorry.

Comment: @Epickel: We can't judge that for you. It makes sense to have a list of `Person` objects for contacts and it makes sense to have a list of names for something like a combobox or several other objects.

Comment: @nhgrif The arraylist is for a jlist

Answer (score 0):

> Now is there a way using the people arraylist to get an arraylist of
>   Name?

**Yes**. Define a name arraylist as `ArrayList<String>`. Than, iterate over  `ArraList<Person>` and put value on name arraylist.

```
List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();

for(Person person : people) {
   nameList.add(person.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to maintain a pair of ArrayLists, one containing `Person` objects, and the other containing the `Name` property of the person objects, you could always create another class:

```
public class PersonList {
    private ArrayList<Person> people;
    private ArrayList<String> names;

    public PersonList() {
        people = new ArrayList<>();
        names = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public PersonList(ArrayList<Person> p) {
        people = p;
        names = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Person person : p) {
            names.add(p.getName());
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Person> getPeople() {
        return people;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getNames() {
        return names;
    }

    public void add(Person p) {
        people.add(p);
        names.add(p.getName());
    }

    public Person getPerson(int index) {
        return people.get(index);
    }

    public String getName(int index) {
        return names.get(index);
    }

    // more methods to continue to replicate the properties of ArrayList...
    // just depends what you need
}
```

You will have to continue adding methods to this class so that this class can do everything that you can do on a single `ArrayList`.  And really, this class is just a convenient way of making it easier to work maintain two different `ArrayLists` at the same time.

Anyway, now in your main code, you can instantiate an object of `PersonList` instead of an array list:

```
PersonList people = new PersonList();
```

And add to `people`.  Or you could even just use a regular array list up until you need the names list, and instantiate a `PersonList` with the other constructor I provided:

```
// Assuming ArrayList<People> arrPeople exists...
PersonList people = new PersonList(arrPeople);
```

And now the `people` object will contain an `ArrayList` identical to `arrPeople`, as well as a matching `names` list containing all the names.  And no matter how you instantiate a `PersonList`, calling the `add` method on a `PersonList` (same syntax as an `ArrayList` if you set this class up correctly), and it will keep both array lists that the class manages in sync.